# Why is my bass clef inverted?

Tags: piano, notation, clefs

I have downloaded an early printed Beethoven sonata where the bass clef is upside down and looks more like a C?  Why?  What am I missing?

Comment: Can we see a picture?

Comment: Not sure what you're missing, but we're missing a picture!

Comment: We need a picture. This could be one of the C-clefs.

Comment: Is it https://vmirror.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/6/60/IMSLP51970-PMLP01446-Beethoven_-_Piano_Sonata_No.1_(Artaria).pdf ?

Comment: Voting to close as "needing details or clarity"

Comment: "What am I missing"?  Nothing.

Comment: @ttw I am not aware of Beethoven using C clefs in piano music, but at any rate C clefs stopped resembling the letter C several centuries before Beethoven.

Comment: I'm not either, but that was my guess. Of course, irregular engraving practice is another option.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an image of the notation and perhaps a link to where you downloaded it from, then your question can be re-opened.

Answer (score 4):

That's common in old scores. I am quite sure I saw it on 19th century orchestra scores, although I cannot state one in particular.

Wikipedia has the answer.
Check [Wikipedia's page on clefs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clef#History), there is a picture of an "inverted" F-clef:

[image: inverted F-clef]

It is said the F-clef "was, until as late as the 1980s in some cases (such as hymnals), or in British and French publications, written like this".

Comment: Thanks for contributing! It would be best to wait until the question is clear enough to answer, though. The wikipedia clef example looks quite different than the one on op 2 no 1 (although the main point is the same, that "it was just done that way").

Comment: @Bonner Well, as I had remarked many times this fancy shape, I felt the question was sufficiently clear. I will post some examples.

Comment: But keep in mind that we're answering *the user's* question. The Wikipedia example curves in the opposite direction from today's F clef, i.e. with the concavity to the right. In that sense it's "like a C." But the 1st edition Beethoven score I linked to still has the concavity to the left, but curves more than a modern F clef (but less than this curlicue); its curvature makes it too "like a C." The question simply isn't clear yet, although as I said the answer is still probably "it was just a practice."

Comment: @Bonner Then I'll wait before posting any example. Which are like the one in Wikipedia, not the one you posted, actually.